# HasFile returns "false" inside asp Panel but outside the Panel its "true"

Tags: c#, asp.net

In File Upload control, **.HasFile** returns "**false**" inside asp Panel but outside the Panel its "**true**".
I have tried alot from Stack Overflow but not succeeded and I don't want to use that "trigger" (sort of) control.

Comment: By "Panel", do you by chance mean "UpdatePanel" control?

Comment: nope, simple asp:Panel

Comment: Show us the code that causes this problem. Having code to look at always helps.

Comment: i got my answer it is as dumb as me i.e [this.Page.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data";], btw thanx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a POST request, you have to encode the data that forms the body of the request in some way.

HTML forms provide three methods of encoding.

application/x-www-form-urlencoded (the default)

multipart/form-data

text/plain

use the following code in your page load

```
this.Page.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data";
```

Comment: it works bro, Thanx.
I was not trying this, just bcoz i was thinking that if it is returning "true" outside the panel then there is no "Enctype" problem.